# Looking for more information on the bridal virginity blessing

Tags: blessing, sources-mekorot, marriage, sexuality

The blessing on [bridal virginity](http://dovbear.blogspot.com/2013/01/the-virginity-blessing.html) is recorded in the Halakhot Gedolot but dismissed by the Rambam in Teshuvot Harambam, II:364-365, #207. What is the original source for this blessing? Do other halachic works discuss it? Does any sect of Judaism recite this blessing nowadays?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22176/759

Answer (score 4):

The ערוך השלחן brings this ברכה in 'סימן ס''ג ס''ק י in which he explains the meaning of the ברכה, quotes several מנהגים, and says that people aren't careful with ברכה now, because it is not found in the גמרא. He then explain that the source of the מנהג is from the סעודה that they used to have after the first ביאה.

Comment: Nice find, but unfortunately the Arukh haShulchan doesn't say where he's getting that information from. As a result, this answers _part_ of the question, but doesn't help with what its original source was (original written source, in any case - unless it's the Halakhot Gedolot), nor with whether or not other halakhic texts discuss it. Do you know if they do?