Do we no longer practice the blessing on virginity and when did it go away?
In the responsa of Rav Hai Gaon (4:8) there is a record of a ceremony conducted after a marriage is consummated wherein the sheet displaying virginal blood is produced and a blessing (or perhaps several blessings) is made. This is known as Birkat HaBetulot and according to sources cited by Professor Marmorstein (The Jewish "Blessing of Virginity", Journal of Jewish Studies, Volume 1, Number 1) was in practice as late as the 15th century.
I would like to know if this ritual is still practiced and if not to see if there is any information as to when it ceased (Rambam in his responsa seems to denigrate it, but the practice persisted after his time).

Some people still say it https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22176/bracha-on-dam-basulim#comment76513_22176

I'm guessing but not certain not saying it might be based on the question, "how would you know the difference between blood of virginity and other blood?".

@Dude there are qualified rabbis that can tell the difference.

More on WIKI page: https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D It says some still say it without Shem and Malchus.

According to a 2003 study published in the Journal of Pediatric and Adolescent Gynecology, only 43% of women reported bleeding during their first sexual encounter. Meaning that if you say a Brocho in public you humiliate the rest 60 percent of Kosher Jewish brides. How sick is it? I should probably ask it as a question.
